# lazy initialization of CDI injected bean in setter

Tags: cdi, jsf-2.2

So I have a bean which contains a category field. If that category field is set to a specific value, for instance "MATCH" I want to initialize a bean. However doing it in the setter of the category is kind of an anti pattern and I'd like to know if in this case that could be considered alright or maybe there is a better way to do it.
I don't want to use postConstruct because the bean is used a really low percentage of the time. So having DB calls in PostConstruct is non sens in my opinion in this case.

```java
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class BeanA implements Serializable {
    private Category category;

    @Inject
    private MatchCreation matchCreation;


    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
        if("MATCH".equals(category.getName()){
             matchCreation.init(); // I'll put a check here to not initialize it twice
        }
    }
}

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MatchCreation {
    private List<Team> teamList;
    private List<Map> mapList;
    @EJB
    private TeamService ts;
    @EJB
    private MapService ms;

    public void init() {
        teamList = ts.getProTeams();
        setMapList(ms.getAllMaps());
    }
}
```

Also in that particular bean I have 9 injections. I don't have to be afraid to use those right, I don't have to try to have the bare minimum ?

Comment: From where are you going to reference the MatchCreation-bean - from a page? Anyway as I understand it I think it is more appropriate to call the init() from for example an actionListener in xhtml

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar oh yeah I didn't think about that !